# how to return an integer value from function without passing any argument in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need one function which read a file and return the number of lines in that file but it will not take anything as an argument.I have written this code but i am getting the error that couldnt match type `IO Int` with `Int`.

I am calling this function from another function as 
  let r=row'
Help me to figure it out
Thanks`

```
row'::()->Int

row' ()=do
  content<-readFile "sample.txt"
  let line_file=lines content
  return (length line_file)
```

Comment: Since you are doing IO, you need to declare your function as such.

Comment: If you have `IO` action, you can't rid from `IO`. In your case the type is `row' :: () -> IO Int`. Sure `()` is unused, you could redefine function to `row' :: IO Int` and `row' = do ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that `readFile` and `return` are `IO` functions, and any function that performs `IO` in Haskell has to denote this in its type.  You could instead write your function as

```
row' :: IO Int
row' = do
    content <- readFile "sample.txt"
    let line_file = lines content
    return (length line_file)
```

And this would compile just fine.  This restriction in the type signature is there to ensure that any function that has side effects or can return different values for the same input is sectioned off by the type system.  This can greatly help in reasoning about your code, since for a pure function, such as

```
countRows :: String -> Int
countRows content = length (lines content)
```

Can always be guaranteed to return the same result for the same input.  Then you can use these "pure" functions in "impure" functions to perform the actual calculations, keeping all the "impure" side effects contained to a single location:

```
row'' :: IO Int
row'' = do
    content <- readFile "sample.txt"
    return (countRows content)
```

Now `row''` doesn't do anything other than read the file and pass the contents to a function that actually performs the work of counting the lines in that file.  You could even state this more simply using `fmap` as

```
row'' :: IO Int
row'' = fmap countRows $ readFile "sample.txt"
```

To use this function, you can do something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Counting the number of rows in sample.txt"
    r <- row''
    putStrLn $ "There are " ++ show r ++ " row(s) in sample.txt"
```

But note that `row''` *must* be called from another `IO` function, you *can not* use it as

```
-- THIS IS WRONG, WON'T COMPILE
doubleRows :: Int
doubleRows = rows'' * 2

-- THIS IS WRONG TOO
doubleRows' :: Int
doubleRows' = do
    r <- rows''
    return (r * 2)
```

because both of these examples would have to have the type `IO Int` instead, and the first one wouldn't compile even with the right type signature because `IO Int * Int` doesn't make any sense, you have to first "extract" the `Int` from `IO Int` using the bind syntax of `r <-`.